# This product release requires the presence of 32-bit compatibility libraries when running on Intel(R) 64 architecture systems

Tags: 12.04

While I am trying to install intel compilers on my Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS it is giving the fallowing error .

```
32-bit libraries not found on this system.
This product release requires the presence of 32-bit compatibility libraries
when running on Intel(R) 64 architecture systems. One or more of these libraries
could not be found:
    libstdc++
    libstdc++5
    glibc
    libgcc
Without these libraries, the compiler will not function properly.  Please refer 
to Release Notes for more information.
```

I tried to download these missing libstdc++5 from `http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25606298/dir/mageia_other/com/libstdc++5-3.3.6-9.mga4.x86_64.rpm.html`

and I added them in  `.._intel64/pset$` path and I tried to reinstall it but it is still asking the same thing.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please type a selection or press "Enter" to accept default choice [1]: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Checking the prerequisites. It can take several minutes. Please wait.

........................../tmp/install.TUMA2Q/li_plugin_bash.qLxuvQ: line 1759: [: 22-6ubuntu1: integer expression expected
.............
```

I found some discussions here and i did the fallowing steps...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
sudo apt-get install rpm
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch.
```

still I am not able to resolve it.

Is this error because of the Ubuntu version I am using. (Should I change the Ubuntu version and If yes, which one?)

How to resolve this problem within on this version, Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

I will be very thank full if some body helps me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, according to https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-compilers-for-linux-with-ubuntu, Ubuntu has deprecated the 32bit libraries.  Packages for 32bit development are nearly impossible to find.  YOU MUST INSTALL the Intel Compilers for 64bit Intel 64 ONLY.

The intel website and the instructions are for Ubuntu version 14.04.

link: [using-intel-compilers-for-linux-with-ubuntu](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-compilers-for-linux-with-ubuntu)

---

The rest of this information is provided as it may be helpful but not as an answer to your question.

The downloaded packages are rpm packages for redhat distros like fedora. Ubuntu is Debian based so we use .deb files instead of .rpm(s).

First, do a quick search of what you are looking for using apt-get. Open a terminal and type the following command:

```
apt-cache search stdc
```

You will see a whole list of related packages and the Debian equivalent will be listed here. To narrow the results, you may want to check out these packages:

```
apt cache search lib32stdc
```

To install any of these packages use the `sudo apt-get` command like in this example:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

The synaptic package manager is a frontend GUI for apt-get and can really help you search for what you need. To install, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

To run, do a search for synaptic in your applications or open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo synaptic
```

Also, there is an intel compiler available through apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install faucc
```